# Electrum - using a fixed fee regardless of transaction size

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, python

I am using Electrum 2.7.12, and I intend to use the python console to paytomany() while using a fixed fee. I have tried following directions from http://matt.ramuta.me/blog/1419787186410-how-to-write-scripts-for-the-electrum-wallet (with a slight workaround for the csv).
How can I create a transaction using paytomany() containing a fixed transaction fee?
Never mind I solved it

Comment: Fixed transaction fee often make little sense. Maybe your transaction require/select 10 inputs and therefore your transaction gets much bigger in size and require more space in the next block. This is why feerates (fee per KB) are mostly the better choice.

Comment: Direct quote from owner of service I am using: "and fee  is as below.
0~1kB : 0.0002 btc
1~2kb : 0.0004 btc
2~3kb : 0.0006 btc", and I doubt I will send transactions with more than 3 or 4 outputs